# How to set different ID's in Angular for HTML elements added with angular.append

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet

Having this code in my directive that holds a leaflet map:

```
angular.element($elem[0]).append(angular.element('<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 25px); border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>'));

map = new L.Map('map', {layers: [osm], center: new L.LatLng(center[0], center[1]), zoom: 10});
```

How do I set different id's for each copy of the directive that I add? This way I could have several copies of the map on screen, instead of the only one I have at the moment. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like that:

```
$scope.mapCount=0;

angular.element($elem[0]).append(angular.element('<div id="map'+ mapCount++ +'" style="width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 25px); border: 1px solid #ccc"></div>'));
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: It does not seem to work:

Error: Map container not found.